# Задача на структуры данных

Tags: c, массивы

Всем привет. Имеется задача:

> Дан список не менее 8 рабочих, ввести фамилию, кол. лет, стаж работы, сколько до пенсии. Вывести кому осталось меньше 15 лет до пенсии.

Я написал такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct raboczii {
    char imja[20];
    char kolvolet[100];
    char staz[50];
}
raboczii;
void main() {
    char str[30];
    int p;
    raboczii working[8] = {
      {
        "Storoz Tolja", "45", 20
      }, {
        "Teteruk Dima", "46", 25
      }, {
        "Chirva Ura", "47", 29
      }, {
        "Ivanov Vasja", "62", 32
      }, {
        "Pupkin Aleksei", "65", 35
      }, {
        "Bil Geits", "22", 2
      }, {
        "Ivan Ivanov", "19", 1
      }, {
        "Petrovicz Petja", "51", 21
      },
    };
    for (p = 0; p < sizeof(working) / sizeof(working[0]); p++) {
      if (working[[p].kol - vo
          let > 60) printf(" %s %s %d\n", working[p].imja, working[p].kolvolet working[p].staz, );
      }
      getch;
    }
```

Пишет ошибку в  `raboczii working[8] =`

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: У вас лишняя запятая лишняя после "{ "Petrovicz Petja", "51",     21 }"
Кстати в "raboczii working[8] =" можно опустить 8 и просто написать "raboczii working[] =" - компилятор по списку инициализаторов сам поймет, какого размера будет массив.
+ У вас в ptintf лишняя запятая в конце списка аргументов
+ Чтобы вызвать getch надо написать getch();, а так как ц вас это просто выражение не делающее ничего.

Comment: все исправил, но все равно пишет ошибка в строке raboczii working[] =, как исправить? я что-т совсем не соображаю(

Comment: Toshka уже исправил)

Comment: И все равно не работает?

Comment: Toshka, не работает

Comment: Стаж - тоже строка? Или как при заполнении массива - int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тако код

```
struct raboczii { 
char imja[20]; 
char kolvolet[100]; 
char staz[50]; 
} raboczii;
```

означает объявление переменной raboczii которая имеет тип структуры struct raboczii
тогда надо либо объявить переменную working типом  struct raboczii, т.е. написать

```
struct raboczii working[8] =...
```

либо (что предпочтительнее), объявить эту структуру типом, т.е.

```
typedef struct { 
char imja[20]; 
char kolvolet[100]; 
char staz[50]; 
} raboczii;
```

Comment: Только вопрос о предпочтительности typedef весьма спорный. Если цель набирать поменьше символов, тогда да. Если надо разобраться, что не работает в чужой большой программе, то нет. 

При большом количестве typedef-ов начинаешь путаться, где структура, где указатель (когда указатели разного типа тоже typedef-ом делают).

Comment: Обычный стиль объявления такой:

    typedef struct raboczii {  
    ...
    } raboczii, *praboczii;

Answer (score 0):

И еще тут ошибка: ты указываешь `char kolvolet[100]`, а потом пишешь `if (working[[p].kol-vo let >60)` тире лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто - в структуре и kolvolet и staz заданы как char, а инициализируются почему то по-разному - kolvolet - как строка, а staz - как число. То есть элементарно не совпадает тип данных.

Я бы определил и kolvolet и staz как int, а в присвоении начальных значений убрал кавычки.

Comment: все равно ошибка есть в строке raboczii working[] = , ((

Comment: А у тебя "{" и "}" всех хватает? Может дело в синтаксисе?

Comment: @Toshka, хватает всего)... да фиг его знает в чем дело)

Comment: @Tim, держись! Найдешь выход! ))

Comment: Конкретно вывод компилятора приведите (и  текст программы точно для этого вывода).

Comment: @Toshka, ой ладно) давайте без фанатизма))
пашел я колдовать)

Answer (score 0):

Объявление массива структуры требует конструктора "по-умолчанию". Объявите такой конструктор, создайте массив, а уж после заполняйте массив конкретикой. [[@Voldemarus](/users/3732/voldemarus)](/users/3732/voldemarus) сделал справедливые замечания + несоответствие типов в printf(...). 
Зачем Вам 100 знаков в возрасте и 50 знаков в стаже? По-моему, у Вас какие-то непонятки с массивом типа char[];

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
typedef struct
{
    char* imja;    //Транслит смотрится ужасно, лучше name
    int kolvolet;  //То же самое, лучше age
    int staz;      //Назвал бы experience
} raboczii;        //А worker было бы лучше
```

Во втором столбике при определении массива нужно убрать кавычки, а в первом аргументе вызова printf передавать " %s %i %in".

> "Bil Geits"

Вообще-то правильно писать Bill Gates.